# Is there a way to create static LSP on a Brocade device?

Tags: brocade, mpls

Is there a way to create a static LSP (i.e. manually specifying in and out labels/interfaces, without LDP or RSVP) on a recent Brocade device running Netiron ?

All I can find is an [old Foundry static MPLS configuration doc](http://www.foundrynet.com/services/documentation/srcli/current/MPLS-static-lsp_cmds.html); however, the `(config-mpls)# static-lsp` command does not exist on my 5.4.0 Ironware. Did they remove the functionality?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: Just checked the literature - doesn't look like static LSP's are supported on MLX/XMR/CES/CER IronWare at least as of 5.2.0. :-/ My Brocade account rep also confirmed that LSP's signaled with RSVP or LDP are the only options and they have no plans to add support back in for static LSP's.

Aside from the above, what you *can* do with RSVP is define a manual ERO for the signaled LSP to traverse, with a combination of `strict` or `loose` attributes.

Example:

```
conf t
router mpls
path test-path-1
  strict 192.168.1.1
  strict 192.168.3.1
path test-path-2
  strict 192.168.1.1
  loose 10.2.1.1
```

`strict` means that traversal of that hop is mandatory. `loose` means that you let CSPF/MPLS TED (populated by OSPF or ISIS) handle how to get to the destination.

And then when you create your LSP, you can tell it to use that specific path as primary/standby etc, ie:

```
lsp test-lsp
  to 10.0.0.1
  primary test-path-1
    adaptive
  secondary test-path-2
    standby
    adaptive
enable
```

I know this doesn't fit your requirement of not using a signaling protocol, but to be honest I'm not sure if any requirement of not using one really makes much sense. Maybe you could elaborate on why you don't want to use RSVP/LDP for signalling?

Comment: This is correct. Static LSPs are not currently supported on the Ironware products

Comment: To answer you question "why?" : this is educational only. I wanted to know if it was possible to learn/teach the principles (not that complicated, I agree) of MPLS without the fuss of a signaling protocol first. The equivalent of static routes for IP routing. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
!
router mpls
 lsp lsp_name
   ....
!
```

Comment: Downvoting, this doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: This doesn't work